# Warn before changing buffer coding system

Tags: character-encoding, warning

Imagine I'm currently editing a file with `iso-latin1-unix` as the
coding system.  I yank some text from another buffer, not noticing its
coding system is `utf-8-unix`.  If the yanked text includes one or
more chars not representable in latin1, emacs will **silently** change
the `buffer-file-coding-system` to `utf-8-unix` the *next time I save
the file*.

I understand this makes sense, since all latin chars can be
represented in utf-8, but I'd like emacs to ask me permission to do
so, or at least warn me about that, since if I don't notice it, lots of
confusion may later occur.  For example, this happened to me in a
LaTeX file: the next time I run LaTeX (several minutes after having
yanked the utf-8 text) I got very confused by the unexpected errors it
spat out.

Ideally, this permission/information would be given as soon as the
'culprit' characters are inserted in the buffer, but at the time of
saving could be ok (I suspect it to be simpler).